Difference between display of webpart in page in edit mode and page in publication
Hello i deployed my webpart on Sharepoint Online on a page and i see a difference in display between edit mode and published page. The webpart contain a scss that i use thanks to
declare module "*.module.scss"; i

n a file typing.d.ts.What should i do?
In the same way there is a difference between the layout in workbench and when i deploy my sspkg.
To deploy here is the process i use:

increased the build number
gulp clean then gulp build --ship, gulp bundle --ship and gulp
package-solution --ship.

Page in Edit mode

Published page


I just found the solution.
Acutally in my file module.scss i changed property of labels from text-align:relative to display:  flex;
